# bathrooms outlets have no power

Tags: receptacle

This is the scenario. Two floor house. The bathrooms' outlets in the second floor have no power. I checked the outlet and there is not a loose wire. I checked the breakers and reset them and electricity is flowing to each branch from the breaker box. I also checked all GfCI outlets in the kitchen and they are all working.
The insulation in the attic is 18 inches making difficult to trace the wire. I do not know where is getting disconnected or loose. Have you dealt with something like this before?

Comment: Bathroom outlets are sometimes wired with other bathroom outlets to make use of a single GFCI outlet device.  Do the outlets have a gfci reset switch, if not, maybe a GFCI in a different bathroom is tripped.  It might even be possible that they are on a GFCI circuit that feeds from an outside GFCI device.

Comment: Also check the garage. Depending on your location and the age of the home bathroom circuits may sometimes be linked to a garage GFCI.

Comment: Yes, check for GFCIs somewhere else in the house.  Also, are the bathroom outlets wired using the side-screws or the backstabs?